# Load DTD with invalid character "-"

Tags: c#, dtd, illegal-characters

I want to load and read a DTD file, the contents of which I have no control over. These DTD files contain lines with characters "-":

> <!ELEMENT Test-ITD  - O (warning) >

So the folowing code fails at the position "-"

```
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.CheckCharacters = false;
settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(strURL, settings);
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(reader);
```

Is it possible to read the DTD with the illegal character?

Comment: Have you investigated *why* you've got broken DTDs? I'd advise you to try hard to get to the root of the problem rather than just working round it.

Comment: Several companies are working with these DTDs . So it will be difficult to get the root of the problem. So I 'm forced to work with the present DTD's...

Comment: I've added to the question the info that you don't control these DTDs.

Comment: If you have invalid data you will need to pre-process it and fix the broken bits before using the XmlReader bits, it shouldn't be too hard in this specific case (if this is everything)

Comment: Do you mean, manually change the DTD ?

Comment: If the files are generated for DTD usage, why do they contain illegal characters? Back to what JonSkeet said, get to the cause of the issue.

Comment: Problem is, there are more illegal charters: <!ELEMENT emphasis  (#PCDATA | quantity | indexFlag | emphasis | subScript | 
               superScript | captionGroup)+ >

Comment: I don't know why there are these characters. Yes these are generated for DTD usage. And so i have no other choice..

Answer (score 1):

Your DTD appears to be designed for a system that processes SGML rather than XML. It is hard to say what you should do about that, but it is not surprising that an XML library rejects the DTD.

The `- O` portion of this element declaration, `<!ELEMENT Test-ITD - O (warning) >`, provides "minimization parameters". It means that the end tag of the element may be omitted. This is a feature that is available in SGML but not in XML.

A second problematic element declaration is mentioned in a comment:

```
<!ELEMENT emphasis (#PCDATA | quantity | indexFlag | emphasis | subScript | superScript | captionGroup)+ >
```

This construct does not work because of restrictions regarding "mixed content". The `+` quantifier cannot be used; only `*` is allowed.

References:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-sgml-xml
- http://www.tei-c.org/Vault/ML/mlw01.htm#ID1

Comment: So there is no chance to load this DTD ?

Comment: I guess not. Perhaps you can contact the people that provide the DTD nd tell them that you can't use it because it's not an XML DTD.